# Pandas Dataframe Reshaping

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as show below

```
>> df

A 1
B 2
A 5
B 6
A 7
B 8
```

How do I reformat it to make it

```
A 1 5 7 
B 2 6 8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Given a data frame like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(one=list('ABABAB'), two=range(6)))
```

you can do

```
df.groupby('one').two.apply(lambda s: s.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack()

#      0  1  2
# one         
# A    0  2  4
# B    1  3  5
```

or *(slightly slower, and giving a slightly different result)*

```
df.groupby('one').apply(lambda d: d.two.reset_index(drop=True))

# two  0  1  2
# one         
# A    0  2  4
# B    1  3  5
```

The first approach works with a `DataFrameGroupBy`, the second uses a `SeriesGroupBy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the series and use [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to keep the correct dimensions.
The order = 'F' makes it scroll through columns (such as `Fortran`), order = 'C' scrolls through rows like `C`
Then it gets into a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(10))
data = df['a'].values.reshape((2, 5), order='F')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=['a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score -1):

how did you generate this data frame. I think it should have been generated using dictionary and then generate dataframe using that dict.
d = {'A': [1,5,7], 'B':[2,6,8]}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d, index=['p1','p2','p3'])

and then you can use df.T to transpose your dataframe if you need to.